# How do I get the number of independent variables from a correlation matrix using R?

Tags: r, matrix, bioinformatics

I have a correlation matrix for several thousand variables (gene expression in the form of a .bed file). Is there a way in R to use this to determine the number of independent variables in the dataset?

Comment: Independent as in independent random variables? Or what is your definition?

Comment: Half the number of values in the matrix that are smaller than a threshold (such as `.Machine$double.eps`)?

Comment: Basically I want to get the correct number of variables to determine the number of tests performed to use in a Bonferroni correction. Is there a standard threshold which is used for this?

Comment: The standard threshold is 1.  *All* variables should be considered as possible predictors.